# Select2-rails passing data to form field

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-4, select2-rails

I'm trying to implement select 2 using the select2-rails gem but I'm not familiar with jQuery or rails.

I basically tried to copy the placeholder example from this website and adapt it to my needs:

http://rails-select2-example.herokuapp.com/

I have a field which lists performers for an event. Originally I just had a simple text field for :performer. But I'd like replace this with a lookup based on my users profile_name which I can then assign to the :performer field.

So I have something like this:

```
<%= select_tag "performer", options_from_collection_for_select(@user, "id", "profile_name"), include_blank: true, id: "performer", data: { placeholder: "Choose a performer" } %>
```

Followed by this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { 
$('select#performer').select2({
placeholder: "Choose a performer",
allowClear: true
});
});
</script>
```

Which works and gives me a dropdown of the users. But I'm not sure how to pass this information to the :performer field. This is probably really simple, so much so that whenever I've searched for simple2 nowhere seems to mention how you pass it to the field. Please help!

Update1:

I can get it to submit by using the following BUT it becomes a simple select box rather than being a select2 autocomplete box.

```
 <%= f.select_tag "performer", options_from_collection_for_select(@user,    
"profile_name", "profile_name"), include_blank: true, id: "performer", data: 
{ placeholder: "Choose a performer" } %>
```

Update2:

Got it to work but still cannot get the placeholder to display.

```
<%= f.select :performer, options_from_collection_for_select(@user,
 :profile_name,:profile_name), {}, include_blank: true, 
id: "performer", data: { placeholder: "Choose a performer" } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing  data:{placeholder:"Choose a performer"} prefer writing  directly after the comma placeholder: "placeholder value" in my opinion it should work .