# rails select2 field not returned into form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select2-rails

This may be a variant of unanswered [Select2-rails passing data to form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461438/select2-rails-passing-data-to-form-field)

I have a field barrister_id in a form

```
<%= form_for(@mail) do |f| %>
  ...
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :barrister_id %><br />
    <!-- %= f.collection_select :barrister_id, Barrister.all, :id, :code_and_name % -->
    <% @barristers = Barrister.all %>
    <%= select_tag :barrister_id,   options_from_collection_for_select(@barristers,
      :id,:code), id: "barristerselect"%>
  </div>
```

The application.html.erb links this to javascript Select2 gem thus:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { $("#barristerselect").select2(); });
</script>
```

and that works to give me the fancy Select2 pulldown of values.

BUT the field value barrister_id is returned only in params.barrister_id, NOT as expected in params.mail.barrister_id, so that the value entered fails validation as being blank.

As shown commented out, I would have preferred to use f.collection_select for the selection box, but couldn't get Select2 to work nice with it.

Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should use f.select in this case. With select_tag you need to do this

```
<%= select_tag "mail[barrister_id]",   options_from_collection_for_select(@barristers,
  :id,:code), id: "barristerselect"%>
```

If you are using f.select then use this. Notice the empty curly braces. That is because html_options is the fourth argument for f.select helper. Checkout the documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select).

```
<%= f.select :barrister_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@barristers,
  :id,:code), {}, id: "barristerselect" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you changed the id of select control. Try to change id to mail_barrister_id (default id generated by select_tag helper). Also should change id in the java script of select2

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the original problem - the field value barrister_id is returned only in params.barrister_id, NOT as expected in params.mail.barrister_id, so that the value entered fails validation as being blank.

Comment: yes, I was wrong. It is not id but name parameter. name should be mail[barister_id]. Try to change yor helper call to `<%= select_tag :barrister_id,   options_from_collection_for_select(@barristers,
      :id,:code), {id: "barristerselect", name: "mail[barrister_id]"}%>`